# Jquery datatable: how can i add a button to the last cell in each row,

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using server side processing with Jquery datatable, but after i retrieve the data and display it on the table, i have no idea on how to add an html button to the end of the row, i tried this:

```
 $('#datatables').DataTable({

        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": {
            "url": "http://localhost:8080/admin/query/fibre",
            "data": function ( data ) {
                //process data before sent to server.
            }},
        "columns": [
            { "data": "id", "name" : "ID", "title" : "ID"  },
            { "data": "name", "name" : "Name" , "title" : "Name"},
            { "data": "time", "name" : "Salary" , "title" : "Salary"},
            {
                "class":          "<button>delete<button>",
                "orderable":      false,
                "data":           null,
                "defaultContent": ""
            },
        ]

    } );
```

but to no avail, any suggestions ? i read this post, but the answer only related to non sever side posting.

This is my html:

```
 <table id="datatables" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Id</th>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th></th>
                            <th></th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tfoot>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Id</th>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Delete</th>
                            <th>Delete</th>
                        </tr>
                        </tfoot>
                        <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                            <td>System Architect</td>
                            <th><button type="button" class="btn purple-gradient btn-sm">Small button</button></th>
                            <th><button type="button" class="btn purple-gradient btn-sm">Small button</button></th>
                        </tr>


                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```

but it seems like it has been overrode by the column{} object

Comment: Use the [defaultContent](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.defaultContent) property?

Comment: Ummm.....maybe you should put your buttons inside `<td>` instead of `<th>` ?

Comment: @9KSoft: I think that the only difference between a `td` and a `th` is the default style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create some content using `columnDef` and `defaultContent`. This is quite the same as what's in the [documentation](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.defaultContent).

```js
$('#datatables').DataTable({
  "columnDefs": [
    {
      "data": null,
      "defaultContent": "<button>Edit</button>",
      "targets": -1
    }
  ]
} );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<table id="datatables" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Delete</th>
      <th>Delete</th>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
      <td>System Architect</td>
      <th><button type="button" class="btn purple-gradient btn-sm">Small button</button></th>
      <th>Whatever that is here will be overwritten</th>
    </tr>


  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use render option here instead. This will allow you to assign dynamic ID/value to your default button.

To assign a dynamic value to button first you have to get the json resonance column value.

**example:** `"data": "add_key_value"`

```
"columnDefs": [ {
                  "targets": -1,
                  "data": "fid", 
                  "render": function ( data, type, row, meta )
                    {
                        return '<button class="btn btn-info" id="'+data+'">view</button>';
                    }
                }]
```

You can find more info and example about render here: [here](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render#Examples)